# Unable to find the index of an element in a complex 2D Python array using np.where()

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to use numpy.where() to find out the index of an element, but it returns an empty array.

```
import numpy as np
grid= np.mgrid[-2:2:5*1j, -2:2:11*1j]
X , Y = grid[0], grid[1]
complex_grid = X+1j*Y
xid, yid= np.where(complex_grid == -1.0 - 0.8j)
print(xid, yid)
```

It should return index (1,3), but it returns an empty array and its data type.
What am I doing wrong?

EDIT :- My main aim is to find the index corresponding to a given coordinate (x,y) from a grid. I made a complex grid just because I can fuse the two 2D matrices I get from mgrid.

Comment: It's almost never a good idea to compare floats by value because of roundoff which can bite you after as simple an operation as computing a range. Compare the absolute or relative difference with a small tolerance instead. Also, there are `np.allclose` and friends.

Comment: Yes, I agree. but will the allclose function work in case of complex too? And how can I use it here

Comment: there is `isclose` which I think is the same without the reduce operation. My guess (not checked) would be it accepts complex, if not do `.real` and `.imag` separately and combine with `logical_and` or `&`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating point values are seldom exact, so it's generally considered a bad idea to directly compare them.

However you can use something like `abs(difference) < epsilon` to check for a given closeness to a value, for example:

```
>>> xid, yid= np.where(np.abs(complex_grid -(-1.0 - 0.8j)) < 1e-10)
>>> print(xid, yid)
[1] [3]
```

or even better: Use [`numpy.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html#numpy.isclose) which already does that but allows relative and absolute tolerances and `nan` handling (if you need these) as well:

```
>>> xid, yid= np.where(np.isclose(complex_grid, -1 - 0.8j)))
>>> print(xid, yid)
[1] [3]
```

Comment: Yes, it was indeed the problem. I just naively thought it might not be a problem although I knew it might be. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

[`isclose()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html#numpy.isclose) is a better choice because comparing floats as equals is always dicey:

```
xid, yid = np.where(np.isclose(complex_grid, np.ones(complex_grid.shape) * (-1.0 - 0.8j)))
```